# Distance from point to n-dimensional line

Tags: algorithms, measurement

The solution for the 3-d case can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html); I would like to get the generalized version.  There's no simple generalization of the Mathworld algorithm since the cross product is defined only for 3 and 7 dimensions, so I understand.

Comment: This is a mathematics question rather than a programming question, isn't it?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I was worried about that but I didn't see a 'Stack Exchange Algorithms' site, and there are lots of algorithms on this site--and FWIW I want this because I need to code it...

Comment: You best bet is probably http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think we could use an appliedmath.stackexchange for this kind of question.  So we could quit bothering the serious mathematicians 8^)

Comment: Wouldn't the computer science exchange be a better fit than the math?

Comment: Even if this weren't more a math question than a programming question, computer science proper doesn't have much to do with this kind of math.  The closest fit to this question that I know of is gamedev.stackexchange.com, but there are plenty of applications for this kind of question outside of game development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use vector algebra (which is easy with a vector algebra library), there is no real difference between the 3-d case and the N-d case.  Unfortunately, the page you link to has written out the vector math element by element, which tends to obscure this.

So, paraphrasing from the article:  given a line through two points `A` and `B`, the minimum distance `d` to a point `P` can be computed as:

```
   n_vector pa = P - A
   n_vector ba = B - A
   double t = dot(pa, ba)/dot(ba, ba)
   double d = length(pa - t * ba)
```

Note that adding two `n_vector`'s is just like adding a 3-vector, except you add N corresponding elements instead of 3 of them, and scaling an `n_vector` by scalar `t` is just like scaling a 3-vector except you scale N elements instead of 3.

Evaluating the `length()` of an `n_vector` is only slightly more complicated:  you sum up the squares of all N elements (instead of just the 3), and take the `sqrt()` of the result.  Finally, as you may have guessed, the `dot()` product is the sum of the products of the N corresponding elements (again, instead of just the 3).

Answer (score 1):

Express the line as a function of a single parameter t.  Call it X(t).

The distance from a point P to a point on the line X(t0) is just u(t) = || X(t0) - P ||, and you don't actually need to do the square root.

Now find the value of t that minimizes u(t).  The standard method from first-semester calculus is to form the derivative du/dt, set it to zero, and solve for t.

If the line is actually a straight line, you will get one solution.  If the line is a curve, you may get many solutions, and you'll have to look at all of them to find the actual minimum.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure derivatives aren't part of the standard 1st semester Calculus curriculum--they weren't in mine--but anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Matt, PLEASE tell me you're joking.  If you didn't cover the basics of integration and differentiation of functions of one variable in 1st semester calculus, what DID you cover?

Comment: Ha, well it was a while ago now but certainly integration, and calculation of the derivative as the limit of (f(x+Dh) - f(x))/Dh.  But DiffEq was a second year course, which is my biggest regret not taking as a math major.  Tufts U., which is not a bad school.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is to minimise the distance between the point and the line.

The line is a set of points. Write an equation to express the distance between the given point and each point in the line - it will be something like `d = sqrt((a1 - b1)^2 + (a2-b2)^2 + ... + (an-bn)^2)`.

Now minimise that equation.

Rather than implement this algorithm yourself, I'd suggest you find a library for linear equations in your chosen language. I've heard of [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) (for Java), but I have never needed to do this so haven't researched it.